# How does the Hamiltonian change when going to a moving frame?

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

The Hamiltonian of a free particle in a rotating frame is given by
$$ H = H_0 - \omega \cdot J, $$
where $H_0$ is the Hamiltonian in the non-rotating frame, $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the frame and $J$ is the angular momentum of the particle.

This relation is too beautiful to be a coincidence. Does it hold for arbitrary systems with rotational invariance? Is a more general statement possible?

Answer (score 1):

At least when the change of frame is given by some canonical flow the situation appears to be quite nice.
If $\phi_t$ is the canonical flow generated by some $J$ and we make the change of frame
$$ x' = \phi_t(x) \,, $$
the Hamiltonian in the new frame is given by
$$ H' = H \circ \phi_t + J \,. $$
Given I didn't make any mistakes deriving this.